# Qual è il significato di "fare aria" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel racconto *I ventitré giorni della città di Alba*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> I partigiani si cacciarono in porte e portoni, i borghesi ruzzolarono in cantina, un paio di squadre corse agli argini da dove aprí un fuoco di mitraglia che ammazzò una vacca al pascolo sull’altra riva e **fece aria** ai repubblicani che però marciaron via di miglior passo.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "fare aria" in questa frase? Ho cercato alla voce "aria" in parecchi dizionari, incluso il dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli. Comunque questa locuzione l'ho trovata soltanto nel [dizionario De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/fare-aria), ma tutte e due le accezioni che ho trovato non sembrano avere senso in questo contesto (penso si tratti di un significato figurato).

Comment: Fu come un colpo di vento, innocuo.

Comment: 'Fece aria' significa che rasentò i repubblicani spaventandoli, per cui 'innocua' non più di tanto. Sennò non si giustifica la parola 'però' successivamente usata dall'autore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'espressione significa  che la raffica di mitragliatrice sparata dai partigiani non fece nessun danno ai repubblichini, innocua proprio come un colpo di vento (come scritto correttamente da egreg nel suo commento).